# Find free port for socket connection on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking

I am writting the appliacation that is using client-server communication.
I was tried to find the way to discover free socket port on mac and was not able to find one using objc. Is there a way to discover free port on mac using objective-c.

I am aware how to do this in C but I wonder if there is a not C way.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an `NSSocketPort`, and then parse its `address` (the bytes of a `struct sockaddr_in`).